# How can I output audio to Monster bluetooth Speakers?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have these monster speakers: Monster BTW249-A

They connect to windows, it says (the speakers have an audio voice that say this) PAIRING

Then it shows up in bluetooth devices and I click the device. Then the speakers tell me "PAIRING COMPLETED".

A few seconds later, I hear it say DISCONNECTED.

I see this window:

[image]

When I click on devices and printers, it's there, but greyed out:

[image]

If I double click on the speaker in devices, I get this window:

[image]

I clicked the link as it said, but it just is stuck on connected like below, it never connects and outputs audio to the speaker:

[image]

I tried a different bluetooth adapter and same thing happens.

I even tried searching google for specific bluetooth drivers for the speaker but couldn't find any.

**Update**: I tried again and this time it installed drivers for the bluetooth speaker and it isn't greyed out; but still won't connect and still says DISCONNECTED right away.

[image]

In windows Manage Audio Devices it shows the bluetooth speaker but it is greyed out as Disconnected:

[image]

And now when I try to click "listen to music" is just says disconnected to me after about 2 seconds every time I try, and unlike before it's not saying "connecting" screen like in the screenshot above.

I tried my phone to connect to the speakers via bluetooth and that worked.

How can I get windows to output the audio to the speakers via bluetooth?

Comment: Is the bluetooth device on your computer a third-party device, or is it embedded in the computer?

Comment: The one embedded in my computer I can't get to work. Both bluetooth devices I tried are both different USB bluetooth adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to get it working.

It seems that my bluetooth dongle didn't work well with the default windows bluetooth drivers.

I found a toshiba bluetooth stack which actually got it working. The downside is it's a 30 day trial, and I hear it's expensive. But at least I know the reason it wasn't working was due purely to a driver issue related to my bluetooth dongle.

Here I installed the toshiba bluetooth stack (I do not have a toshiba PC, it is just developed by toshiba):

[image]

It didn't work the first time but I uninstalled the bluetooth drivers in device manager and made sure to choose "delete drivers".

Then I restarted my PC, and then I reinstalled the toshiba bluetooth stack and restarted my PC with the dongle in.

My computer took longer than usual to start up and I got a little worried but then finished starting up just fine.

I clicked on the icon in the taskbar (I blurred out my personal info):

[image]

I put my speakers in pairing mode and chose the Express setup (recommended)" option and pushed Next while my speakers were in pairing mode.

It finished up and automatically configured everything to work.

As you can see now my monster bluetooth speakers are fully set up. They now work automatically via bluetooth.

[image]

Here's a couple more helpful info:

The version I installed of the bluetooth stack:

[image]

My bluetooth dongle (had it for years, now it can be bought for like $2 though):

[image]

Not sure what I will do after 30 days but at least for now my bluetooth is working and my bluetooth speakers are connected via bluetooth and playing audio.

Update: I tried to find where I could even buy it, and on the Toshiba website I found this:

```
Please note that TOSHIBA Bluetooth Stack for users without TOSHIBA hardware isn't available anymore.
```

So what's going to happen after 30 days? Dunno.

Update: version 9.10.11 has bluetooth 4.0 support also.

And since it's not actually available for purchase anymore (but yet isn't deprecated?!!) I found a torrent with a crack and that will work well for me. Silly Toshiba, if you weren't going to support the software or even sell it then you should have just made it free!

Comment: Just an update: what I did after 30 days is that I had my laptop manufacturer ship me a replacement wireless card, because it was supposed to have bluetooth included. After I got the new wireless card I was able to get bluetooth working, and then I didn't have to use any dongle. Hope it helps!